# Receive e-mail on AWS SES from one, but only one, e-mail address

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, email-server, mx-record, amazon-ses

I have an app for which e-mails sent to a specific address, x@example.com, should be received by SES for analysis of e-mail attachment and storage. However, I would like to handle the other E-mail addresses, y@example.com, z@example.com, associated with the domain outside of SES.

To receive the e-mail sent to x@example.com, I need to change the MX record for example.com. As I understand it, this means that the handling of e-mails moves from my domain to aws, for all e-mail addresses.

Is there a way to set SES to receive only mail from a specific address and leave the rest alone? For example by forwarding x@example.com to SES?

Some thoughts:

- I guess I could use SES to handle all e-mail addresses, but y@example.com and z@example.com are for manual communication, so I want to use these in my standard e-mail program (e.g. Outlook or Gmail). It would also mean that I would have to pay for receiving all e-mails at SES, which seems a bit stupid.
- Could I set up a subdomain and set the MX record for only this domain? E.g. x@sub.example.com. This doesn't seem possible at my domain handler.

UPDATE:

I followed AlexD's answer below, but it doesn't seem to work like intended. I now have the (verified) subdomain sub.example.com with the MX record set. E-mails sent to x@example.com are redirected to x@sub.example.com - but they are not received by SES.

It seems that SES will not accept the e-mail when it is a forwarding. If I send directly to x@sub.example.com I receive it on SES without problem. I know the forwarding works as I am forwarding to another address as well without issue. In fact, if I send and e-mail from one of my own e-mail addresses to another and then forward that e-mail myself to x@sub.example.com, it is not received by SES.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sub-domain `app.example.com` and set its `MX` to `SES` and then forward `x@example.com` to `x@app.example.com`.

Comment: ah, thanks! That's close to what I have in mind, but I couldn't find settings for creating e-mail addresses or setting MX for a subdomain, if what you say is possible, it must be a problem at my specific domain handler, Simply.com...

Comment: it seems that this method does not actually work. I have edited my question with an update.

Comment: If SES doesn't accept forwarded emails then you need to check if you have the correct SPF settings, but this is a separate question. Alternatively, you can drop forwarding and use x@app.example.com directly.